# Bootstrapping maps inside partial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Recently I was trying to incorporate map inside partial using anuglar native ui.map. Hovewer, it seems that my partial is trying to initialize map controller before I bootstrap it. What should be done to initialize all elements in order?

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('mapApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'mainControllers', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.map']).config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
    controller : 'homeCtrl'
});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/'
    });
}]);
```

**controllers.js**

```
function onGoogleReady() {
    console.log("Google maps ready!");
    angular.bootstrap($('#map'), ['mapControllers']);
}

var controllers = angular.module('mainControllers', []);
var mControllers = angular.module('mapControllers', ['ui.map']);

controllers.controller('homeCtrl', ['$rootScope',
function($rootScope) {
   $rootScope.active = 0;
}]);

mControllers.controller('mapCtrl', ['$scope',
function($scope) {
    console.log("Map controller initialized NOW!!!");
    $scope.mapOptions = {
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(35.784, -78.670),
        zoom : 15,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
}]);
```

**home.html**

```
<div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Main home template</h1>
</div>
<div id="map" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
    <div ui-map="myMap" ui-options="mapOptions" class="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

**index.html script includes (in the bottom of the file)**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=onGoogleReady"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-map/ui-map.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
```

Returned error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'mapCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

Comment: where u include `controllers.js` ?

Comment: Asynchronously on the bottom of my body. I added edit to my main message with details :)

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that using ng-app directive lead to bootstrapping every part of the code without possibility of controlling it directly. To properly manually bootstrap the controller I had to remove this directive and use only "ng-controller" directive inside proper div. After removing ng-app everything seemed to work fine - controller was bootstrapped after google maps were loaded and model was available to underlying elements.